# Opening the most recently hidden buffer in Vim

Tags: vim

Assuming that I have two buffers. One is NERDTree, the other is an actually file I'm editing. I accidentally open an another file from NERDTree and the new file hides the previous file I was editing.

A similar case occurs whether I use NERDTree or not.

How can I bring back the previous state by opening the mostly recently hidden file? I'm using the word "hide" because this is probably not "closing".

Comment: If anybody wants to read the help doc, type in `:h CTRL-6` in Vim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>6</kbd> to switch back to the previous buffer in the window.

Comment: to open alternate buffer in new window `Ctrl-w Ctrl-6`

Comment: cool.  i have been using :e# my whole life which is not as convenient.  but it is easier to remember.  i guess....